Can I use transit visa to visit UAE, If I am not transiting to a third country?
Can I use a transit visa to visit UAE and come back to India if my stay is just for one day?
I am Indian citizen and would like to visit Dubai just for one day, can I use transit visa for 48 hours to enter the country and take a flight back to India, instead of going to a third country?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Clarified the question.

so you want to abuse a transit visa as a short stay tourist visa. What makes you think that's going to work, or a good idea at all?

No, you cannot.  A transit visa is for going through (transiting) a country on your way to a final destination somewhere else, you cannot use one (and the airline will not even let you board) if all you have is a return ticket from and back to India.
Per u.ae (official UAE government site), transit visa requirements are:

a passport or travel document with a minimum validity of three months
a photo of self against a white background
an onward ticket booking to a 3rd destination, other than the one you are coming from.


To add to that, eventhough the transit country may not care, you won't be getting in that flight. For instance, in Singapore, they provide free transit visa for people with US, UK and some other visas. They won't check the onward flight. But, Airline in India is not going to allow you to board.

@AnishSheela it's worse than that: in the UAE, you can only get a transit visa through an airline based in the UAE, so you're not going to get the visa in the first place.

@phoog actually we can get the visa from vfs website

@DeepSleep you can, but VFS will obtain the visa on your behalf from the airline, and they will not be able to do that unless you have an appropriate flight.  In fact, VFS only handles visas for Emirates passengers; they don't work with Etihad.
